# dataframe copy row to a new dataframe if it contains a specific string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

i have this dataframe :

```
name id country 
Jeff  -   -
Lisa  -   -
```

if df['id'] contains this string (-), I want all the row to be copied to a new dataframe. How can i do it?

Comment: or this, ``df[df.id.str.strip() == '-']``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'name':['A','B','C','D','E'],
    'ID': ['a','b','-','-','e'],
    'country':['usa','sa','-','uk','-']
                         })
```

Data frame look like this

```
    name    ID  country
0   A      a    usa
1   B      b    sa
2   C      -    -
3   D      -    uk
4   E      e    -
```

Index the ID columns where - is present

```
new_id=df[df['ID']=='-']
```

Result

```
    name    ID  country
2   C       -   -
3   D       -   uk
```

If you want to find all other rows where both country and ID has -, you can do this

```
new_df=df[(df['ID']=='-') & (df['country']=='-')]
```

Result will be

```
    name    ID  country
2   C        -   -
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
 df_new = df.loc[df.loc[df.ID == "-", 'ID'].index.values]
```