# Importing Excel file into Panda (Python) using conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-2.7

I am using Python 2.7.18.4 (I know an old version, but I cannot change) to import a set (probably around 1000, maybe more) of Excel files. Each Excel file contains the same column I am interested, but it is everytimes written differently. My idea was the following: Using Python & Pandas I wanted to import one Excel file and then check if the content I need is useful. The content I need looks like this:

| Item | Parcelnumber | Amount | Series |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 72GW99752 | 3 | POKDUS |
| 1 | 72GW99753 | 548 | PDGCHG |
| 0 | 233AWW997T52 | 35 | SYDIUM |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| Total | NONE | 235 | NONE |

Before and after this table is content too, but I am not interested in this, so I want to skip it. I want to use everything from `Item` until `Total` (since `Total` is somehow a recap/control of the previous values, but we could also skip this one, if needed). I read in the [following thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62871223/dataframe-copy-row-to-a-new-dataframe-if-it-contains-a-specific-string) that using Pandas and looping through a dataframe and then copying the important is not "wise" since Pandas is used for mass-usage.
However this answer I am interested:

`df_new = df.loc[df.loc[df.ID == "-", 'ID'].index.values]`

Can the part where the verification is be "abused" in order to check if my content is between the `Item` and the `Total` line?

Comment: Just use `openpyxl` (assuming it's compatible with Python 2.7) to read the Excel file - you don't need dataframes for this.

Comment: Is a "verification" like I need then even possible to create in openpyxl?

Comment: Openpyxl just parses Excel files; you'd iterate over the rows like any data.